# How contacts from older version are treated when I activate new version of a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've prepared a journey which is around 15 days long. Now I want to do some modification in the same.

1. What happens to contacts which are there in journey (older version), if I simply go and activate new version and don't do any change in older version. Does sfmc flush out all contacts in older version at the time of activation of new version or they will still go through remaining journey.
2. What happens to contacts in older version, if I stop older version and then activate new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the old version running it'll be in status `Finishing`, which means it will continue to work exactly as it was designed and activated for.

**Question 1** - the Contacts will continue through that version of Journey, they will not be thrown out even if the new version if activated. Contacts in it will continue to interact and exit normally.

**Question 2** - if you STOP a Journey, then all Contacts currently in it will be thrown out of that version and that version of Journey will show you status as `Stopped`.

Documentation links:

- [Stopping a Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_stop_journey.htm&type=5)
- [Journey Statuses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_statuses.htm&type=5)
- [Active Journey vs Inactive](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_active_vs__inactive_versions.htm&type=5) (explains this topic well)