# Journey Builder re-entry, versions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have the following set-up

- Journey entry point is a Data Extension
- Records are added to the DE on a daily basis through an automation
- Contact Evaluation = The journey will evaluate all new records
- Re-entry mode = No re-entry

The DE now contains around 10.000 records, but only the new records added by the Automation are send every day (around 200).

If I create a new version (not a copy) of the journey and activate it, will it send a mail to the 10.000 again? Or only to the new records that are added by the automation the next day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. **No**, the emails will not be sent again to the contacts already in your Data Extension. Only new ones will be injected in your new version of your Journey and hence receive the email.

I would have given you links to the official documentation, but it's not working right now (SF bug?)

Anyways, check out Rain's answer for more information about Journey Statuses and behaviours:

[How contacts from older version are treated when I activate new version of a journey?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247375/how-contacts-from-older-version-are-treated-when-i-activate-new-version-of-a-jou)

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I was also going through the official documentation and was facing 404's :)